# sample make file for creating more than one exe files with different directory

Tags: c, makefile

I am having a directory called test where make file should be. i am having subdirectory called sub1, sub2, sub3.

> test/Makefile
>
> test/sub1
>
> test/sub2
>
> test/sub3

I want to create exe1 by compiling sub1, exe2 by compiling sub2 and exe3 from sub3.

Can i add more than one directory in vpath?? or any other solution

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have a very simple makefile in the `test` directory, just going into the subdirectories and calling makefiles in them. The subdirectories have makefiles that builds normally, but simply put the executable in the parent directory.

Comment: thank you, i understand what you said. can i get a sample makefile.

Comment: @user2732944 There are literally *hundreds* of samples in [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) for gnu-make.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Yes you could add more than one directory in vpath. Each entry is separated with a colon ':'

```
vpath %.c test/sub1:test/sub2:test/sub3
```

But you'll getting into trouble as soon you have the same filename (with different content) in two directories. Consider:

```
test/Makefile
test/sub1/main.c
test/sub1/foo.c
test/sub1/bar.c
...
test/sub2/main.c
test/sub2/blish.c
test/sub3/blash.c
...
test/sub3/main.c
test/sub3/okEnoughForNow.c
```

And your makefile containing:

```
vpath %.c sub1:sub2:sub3

exe1.exe : main.c foo.c bar.c
    gcc -o $@ $^

exe2.exe : main.c blish.c blash.c
    gcc -o $@ $^

exe3.exe : main.c okEnoughForNow.c
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

The result would be:

```
gcc -o exe1.exe sub1/main.c sub1/foo.c sub1/bar.c
gcc -o exe2.exe sub1/main.c sub2/blish.c sub2/blash.c
gcc -o exe3.exe sub1/main.c sub3/okEnoughForNow.c
```

As you can see, all exe's contain `sub1/main.c` as this is the main.c found first; Its path appears first on the vpath.

Joachim's Approach is definitive a simple, and very common solution. I would choose it as well if the programs in your subfolders are completely unrelated: You could have in each directory a makefile containing something like:

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)

%.exe : $(SRC)
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

Assuming, all .c files in each of your sub* shall be part of your program, and there are no subfolders in your sub's. Otherwise you'll need a different approach to scan your .c files, or specify them individually.

In your main makefile you can run for each subfolder a new instance of make, using those makefiles. Which gives you a main Makefile like:

```
# Get all subfolders name without trailing slash
PROGS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(wildcard */))

# Each subfolder can be made by calling make in
# that folder. A file prog.exe is created.
.PHONY : $(PROGS)
$(PROGS) :
    $(MAKE) -C $@ prog.exe

# Now every .exe depends on its subfolder, calls
# Make there - see rule above and copies the
# prog.exe from there into the root, with the name
# of the subfolder. (Alternatively you could use
# mv instead of cp)
%.exe : %
    cp $</prog.exe $@
```

Assuming the name of your .exe is the same as the directory name and all subfolders are containing programs.

However, calling make from a running make instance (recursive make) can cause a real headache as soon as there are any dependencies between the generated files of the subfolders.

## Another solution:

A different approach **whithout using recursive make** is having rules dynamically created. In that case your main Makefile could look like this. (I'm again assuming all subfolders are containing programs, all subfolders are flat, and all .c files in those subfolders are part of your program) This has the advantage that you'll have to maintain just one makefile, and there can be any dependency between the different programs. But still it has the disadvantage that you cannot manage your different programs seperately.

That's the complete makefile:

```
%.exe :
    gcc -o $@ $^

PROGS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(wildcard */))
$(foreach P,$(PROGS),$(eval OBJ_$(P) := $(wildcard $(P)/*.c)))
$(foreach P,$(PROGS),$(eval $(P).exe : $(OBJ_$(P))))

.PHONY : all
    all : $(addsuffix .exe,$(PROGS)
```

We're starting with a rule for compiling: Any .exe is generated by invoking gcc having all prerequisites as source files.

```
%.exe :
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

Then, next step is to obtain all "programs" by scanning for all subfolders and stripping off the trailing slash

```
PROGS := $(patsubst %/,%,$(wildcard */))
```

The next step is to create for each program a variable containig all Sources. Note the eval function expands, and passes everything to make as it has been written in the Makefile.

```
$(foreach P,$(PROGS),$(eval SRC_$(P) := $(wildcard $(P)/*.c)))
```

Thus the line above, with your `sub1`, `sub2` and `sub3` will become:

```
SRC_sub1 := $(wildcard sub1/*.c)
SRC_sub2 := $(wildcard sub2/*.c)
SRC_sub3 := $(wildcard sub3/*.c)
```

The eval function can even be used to create rules:

```
$(foreach P,$(PROGS),$(eval $(P).exe : $(SRC_$(P))))
```

So this will expand to (assuming the file structure in the example above)

```
sub1.exe : sub1/main.c sub1/foo.c sub1/bar.c
sub2.exe : sub2/main.c sub2/blish.c sub2/blash.c
sub3.exe : sub3/main.c sub3/okEnoughForNow.c
```

Now we have three rules without a recipe. Make says "if you have a rule without recipe, and an implicit rule that matches can be found, this rule is used with the prerequisites added from the rule that does not have the recipe" Thus, for those 3 rules the implicit rule of %.exe above applies.

Basically that's the trick. For your convenience you can add

```
.PHONY : all
all : $(addsuffix .exe,$(PROGS))
```

So `make all` makes everything.

**Extension:**

If you'd like to be able to make the .o files seperately as well, you could add one more implicit rule like:

```
%.o : %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

and make your programs dependent on the .o rather than on the .c files:

```
$(foreach P,$(PROGS),$(eval OBJ_$(P) := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard $(P)/*.c))))
$(foreach P,$(PROGS),$(eval $(P).exe : $(OBJ_$(P))))
```

Then you'll have your .exe dependend on the .o that can be found by changing .c into .o after scanning all sources. Via the implicit rule chain %.o : %.c make will know what to do.